# Passport pages full of stamps + valid Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, switzerland

Can I enter Switzerland with a multiple entry visa issued by the French embassy and with no blank page on my passport ?

Comment: You need space for entry and exit stamps. Perhaps your country can invalidate your current passport and give you a new one. You could travel with both together.

Comment: @Annoyed: You don't need a new passport if you have space for stamps but not full-page visas when you already have any full-page visas required for the trip in question though.

Comment: Frangipane: Do you mean every page is full, or just that every page has at least one stamp, but some of them still have space for other stamps? You shouldn't need a *blank* page, but you will need some space.

Answer (score 5):

Switzerland is now part of Schengen. If you travel from a Schengen country, you will not go through immigration. So long as your Schengen visa is valid, you can remain within the Schengen space including Switzerland.

Comment: Good point, that might not have been clear to the OP. But the blank page issue would come up when you are entering from a non-Schengen country. You do need to get your passport stamped on entry and exit, whether you enter through the country that issued the visa or not.

Comment: But is it a requirement of Schengen that the stamp can only go on a blank page? Or is it a very large stamp that requires a whole page? I get visa-free entry to Schengen and have many small stamps from various Schengen countries, so unless there is some other large stamps only issued to people who need a Schengen visa I don't see a problem.

Comment: @hippietrail The stamps are the same as far as I know and I have no reason to think they need to go on a completely blank page, I was just highlighting that it was the question being asked.