# Schengen Visa require 2 blank pages. 2 both side blank pages? or one side blank

Tags: visas, schengen

HI I am applying for a Schengen visa. I have one page with both sides blank and two one side blank pages in my passport. Is it enough for Schengen Visa?

They say that I need two blank pages. Is it both side blank or will one side blank do?

Comment: It's more than enough, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21317/schengen-visa-in-almost-full-passport?rq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/passport-pages-full-of-stamps-valid-schengen-visa?rq=1